# Update dynamic elements

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to update a list of lights on the scene. For this I keep the last list and delete all the elements, and create new ones based on the new list... 
It deletes all the elements just fine, but when I try to update with the new ones.. it just crashes and says:

RuntimeError: Object's name 'textName1' is not unique. #

It's suposed to be deleted, isn't it??

this is the code of this part..

```
def updateList(self, name, totalLgt, *args):
    print "update %s" % name
    #create new buttons

    self.text = pm.text('textName'+str(totalLgt), label="Name: %s" %name)
    self.button = pm.button('btnName'+str(totalLgt), label="ON" ,command = lambda *args: self.turnOn(totalLgt, name))
    self.button = pm.button('btnNameS'+str(totalLgt), label="SOLO", command = lambda *args: self.turnSolo(totalLgt, name))

def update(self, totalLgt,lis, *args):
   totalLgt = 0
   for lgt in lis:
        totalLgt += 1

   i = 1
   print "updatea"
   print lis
   for i in range(totalLgt):
      if (pm.window('textName'+str(i+1), exists=True)):
         pm.deleteUI('textName'+str(i+1), control = True)
         pm.deleteUI('btnName'+str(i+1), control = True ) 
         pm.deleteUI('btnNameS'+str(i+1), control = True )

   lisN = pm.ls(type='light') 
   totalLgt = 0 
   #list all lights in scene
   for lgt in lisN: 
      totalLgt += 1
      nameLgt = lgt.longName()
      name = nameLgt.split("|")[1]
      self.updateList(name, totalLgt)
```

The prints of the list and the new list are correct, so I'm not sure why it fails...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work adding a layout with all the buttons there and deleting that layout =)